# Can a CA be defeated by MitM in order to deliver a signed certificate to the attacker instead of the legitimate owner?

Tags: certificate-authority

Some Certificate Authorities (such as Let's Encrypt) authenticate that the client controls the server by telling you to put up a secret string in a well known file on your server.

So it goes

```
CA -> You (qwerty...)
You -> Server (qwerty...)
CA --Verifies-> Server
```

But what happens if someone MITM *the CA*?

For example what if Chuck managed to take control of the wire between the CA to Server. He requests a certificate for veryimportantwebsite.com (which he doesn't control). The CA says "Ok. Put "qwerty" in $WELLKNOWNFILE". He can't do *that* (as he doesn't control the server), but what he can do that when the CA connects to http ://veryimportantwebsite.com/$WELLKNOWNFILE , he responds with "qwerty".

The CA says "Ok. I'll sign your public key".

Now, you'll say, why can't the CA connect with HTTPS? Because you're putting the cart before the horse. The CA doesn't know (and can't know) that veryimportantwebsite.com already has an HTTPS certificate (as the MITM can block port 443).

Comment: Your premise is that some threat actor has _already_ compromised the CA’s security and can decrypt TLS-protected traffic, even DNS-poison the CA’s network. From that premise anything is possible. Why not straight away steal the CA’s root certificate along other the private key and sign Let’s Encrypt certificates yourself?

Comment: CAs have been compromised in the past and generally this bodes very bad for them, as their keys are not trusted anymore by users.

Comment: @korrigan **Your premise is that some threat actor has already compromised the CA’s security and can decrypt TLS-protected traffic** No. The issue is that until the client-server (veryimportantwebsite.com) has https (meaning, _after_ the CA finishes signing the certs), all communication is over http, which can be intercepted on the wire.

Comment: I reread your question. Actually you rule out any action from the legitimate server, and it’s your MitM server initiating the process, so you don’t need to break encryption (whereas I understood you were hijacking a legitimate signing process where TLS is used for anything other than validating the secret on the candidate server). Actually http(s) matters little in this scenario — the CA is already not talking to the right server in the first place. While theoretically possible, it’s hard to MitM a whole network, unless it has a single exit point, which is another story I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAs use various techniques to protect against this, but at the end of the day, an adversary with the capability to do this is likely to succeed.  For example, Let's Encrypt [requests the well-known file from multiple networks](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/validating-challenges-from-multiple-network-vantage-points/40955), so a MITM is more likely at your end than at the CA.

Almost all Domain Validation schemes fall prey to attacks like this:

1. Email validation based on WHOIS data?  Hijack the WHOIS server, or intercept the email since almost no mail servers use SMTP over TLS with certificate validation.  (They usually ignore certificate errors.)
2. DNS record validation?  Hijack DNS.  (That happens a lot already.)
3. SNI validation?  MITM the server (same as HTTP)

As a site owner, monitoring Certificate Transparency logs can help, as can implementing DNSSEC (especially with CAA).

Answer (score 0):

Let's encrypt calls veryimportantsite.com over the internet, if the attacker managed to MiTM that, then there are a lot more issues to worry about. Usual man-in-the-middle is due to someone jacking the local WiFI etc.

That is where HSTS comes into play, because the local whiz-kid whose owned the coffeeshop WiFi wouldn't be able to generate a cert for veryimportantsite.com, and if the site had HSTS, this would make MiTM difficult.

But if you've successfully controlled the entry point to a datacenter, and can MiTM all traffic to servers, then I guess yes, you can create a new cert for sites hosted on servers in that DC.

You still won't get EV certs, but DV certs from Let's encrypt would be possible.

The one mitigation is that Let's Encrypt issues short-live certs, so when discovered, this would have an impact measured in months, not years. CRL and OSCP would also help revoke the cert before the due-date.

Certificates aren't perfect, but they're better than nothing.

Comment: **That is where HSTS comes into play,** You can't use HSTS before  veryimportantsite.com has https set up.